# Delphi Edit Text Integer: Minus Sign Error

Tags: delphi, sign

Hi I am very beginner for Delphi.
But what confuses me is that I have Edit1.Text
and variable "i" which uses StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
Everything is Ok until I type minus sign

If I copy/paste minus with number (eg -2) it works 
Can Anyone help me! 
Regards, Umar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`StrToInt`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StrToInt) conversion function is unsafe to use when you're not 100% sure the input string can be converted to an integer value. And the edit box is such an unsafe case. Your conversion failed because you've entered as a first char the `-` sign that cannot be converted to integer. The same would happen to you also when you clear the edit box. To make this conversion safe, you can use the [`TryStrToInt`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TryStrToInt) function, which handles the conversion exceptions for you. You can use it this way:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  // if this function call returns True, the conversion succeeded;
  // when False, the input string couldn't be converted to integer
  if TryStrToInt(Edit1.Text, I) then
  begin
    // the conversion succeeded, so you can work
    // with the I variable here as you need
    I := I + 1;
    ShowMessage('Entered value incremented by 1 equals to: ' + IntToStr(I));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @Ken, d'oh. It was intended to be just a temporary post. Now I need to think up some text to the code.

Comment: You can see my deleted one, right? Feel free to help yourself if there's anything useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

You get an error, obviously, because `-` is not an integer. You can use TryStrToInt instead.

Comment: But I am just starting to type (eg -7), of course first you type - and then 7. But delphi gives error on first

Comment: Assuming you have your `StrToInt` conversion code in `OnChange` event, it fails because the `OnChange` event fires for every edit box text change. When you type `-` sign as first char, the `OnChange` event fires and performs your `StrToInt` conversion, which fails because the `-` sign is not an integer. Similar error you get also when you clear the edit box.

Comment: As Rob suggested, you can use the [`TryStrToInt`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TryStrToInt) function. It tries to convert the string passed as a first parameter to integer and if succeeds, it returns True as a result and the integer value returns to the second parameter. If the conversion fails it returns False. So you can use it like I've shown in my temporary post below.

Comment: Finally got it onExit for example. Thanks Everyone